# Cloud Dataflow autoscaling messages

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

According to the [FAQ's](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/faq#question-31), autoscaling is off by default when spinning up the worker pool. We've set "numworkers" to 5, and the algorithm type to "NONE" using the enum [`AutoscalingAlgorithmType`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.AutoscalingAlgorithmType)

However, we're still seeing the following message when our job is running:

> (f8775c76163306ae): Autoscaling: Resizing worker pool from 0 to 1.

It's not causing a problem as far as we can tell, but I'd like to know why we're seeing this, and whether or not it's intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message can safely be ignored.  Its appearance is a known issue, and does not affect the behavior of your pipeline.